# Should we update the "debug my code" close reason?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

When we [first discussed the "debug my code" close reason](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1543/should-we-create-a-debug-my-code-close-reason) we settled on the following wording that is in-use today:

> Questions about debugging a problem in your
>   project must present a concise selection of code and context so as to allow a
>   reader to diagnose the issue without needing to read
>   *all* of your code or to engage in extensive back-and-forth
>   dialog. For more information, see [this meta
>   thread](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1537/what-counts-as-a-debug-my-code-type-of-question)

Many of the questions we got back then that this reason would pertain to were large, context-free code dumps. Recently I've noticed we're getting a lot of "debug my code" questions that either aren't strictly code-related or do include very concise (but not at all relevant) code samples.

Consequently I think we should update the close reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think we should change the reason to include wording requiring a minimal example that would reproduce the problem. I've created the [What's a "minimum complete verifiable example" (MCVE) and how do I provide it?](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2201/whats-a-minimum-complete-verifiable-example-mcve-and-how-do-i-provide-it) meta post, cribbed from the StackOverflow help pages (an idea I stole from [Vi and Vim](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1325/how-to-create-a-minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example)), which we can use to request users provide such an example. I propose we update the close reason text as follows:

> Questions about debugging a problem must provide a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2201) of the issue so
>   that readers can diagnose it without needing to guess, read *all* of your code, or engage in extensive back-and-forth dialog. For more information, see [this meta
>   thread](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1537).

Comment: This is now live.